# ActionView FormHelper Input with data behavior HTML options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

My form tag looks like

```
<%= form_for [ conversation, Message.new ], remote: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>
  <%= form.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

how can I add this HTML data options:

```
<input data-behavior="message_speaker">
```

to the `form.text_area` element?

Comment: like : `:data-behavior => "message_speaker"`

Comment: that gives me `undefined local variable or method `behavior' for #<#<Class:0x00000012039820>:0x000000105f67d8>´

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= form.text_area :body, :class => 'form-control', data: { behavior: "message_speaker" } %>
```